# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier, could someone help me?

Tags: blockchain

Smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Lottery {
    address public owner;
    address payable[] public players;
    uint public lotteryId;
    mapping (uint => address payable) public lotteryHistory;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        lotteryId = 1;
    }

    function getWinnerByLottery(uint lottery) public view returns (address payable) {
        return lotteryHistory[lottery];
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        // address of player entering lottery
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function getRandomNumber() public view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(owner, block.timestamp)));
         require(players.length >= 3 , "Not enough players in the lottery");
    }

    function pickWinner() public onlyowner {
       winner.transfer( (getBalance() * 80) / 100);
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);

        lotteryHistory[lotteryId] = players[index];
        lotteryId++;
        

        // reset the state of the contract
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }

    modifier onlyowner() {
      require(msg.sender == owner);
      _;
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contracts/Lottery.sol:41:8:
|
41 | winner.transfer( (getBalance() * 80) / 100);
| ^^^^^^

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contracts/Lottery.sol:42:17:
|
42 | players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
| ^^^^^

DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contracts/Lottery.sol:44:45:
|
44 | lotteryHistory[lotteryId] = players[index];
| ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This errors specify that you must to declare variables where compiler give you error.
In your case, you did not declare these variables:

- winner;
- index (inside pickWinner function).

I tried to solve your problem, check this smart contract and checking if logic correspond with your smart contract logic:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Lottery { 
    address public owner;
    
    address payable[] public players;
    uint public lotteryId;
    mapping (uint => address payable) public lotteryHistory;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        lotteryId = 1;
    }

    function getWinnerByLottery(uint lottery) public view returns (address payable) {
        return lotteryHistory[lottery];
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        // address of player entering lottery
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function getRandomNumber() public view returns (uint) {
        require(players.length >= 3 , "Not enough players in the lottery");
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(owner, block.timestamp)));
    }

    function pickWinner() public onlyowner {
        // NOTE: Retrieve a number from getRandomNumber() function
        uint index = getRandomNumber();
        // NOTE: Declare a variable that it'll contain the winner address
        address payable winner = players[index];
        winner.transfer((getBalance() * 80) / 100);
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
        lotteryHistory[lotteryId] = players[index];
        lotteryId++;
        // reset the state of the contract
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }

    modifier onlyowner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
}
```

***ADVICE***: You don't use block.timestamp for calculate a random number, because a miner studying your smart contract's logic can manipulate block.timestamp parameter. If you  don't want to have this problem use [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/) for generate random numbers.